# Съезжает футер (html, css)

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том, что когда товары не находятся, футер съезжает вот таким образом. Знает кто как решить?
[image: то, как футер и съехал]

Вот html:

```
<div class="container">
  <footer class="footer">
    <nav class="footer__nav">
      <img src="../../static/main/img/logo-orange.svg" class="footer__logo">
      <a href="" class="footer__el">Головна</a>
      <a href="/products" class="footer__el">Страви</a>
      <a href="#" class="footer__el">Ціни</a>
      <a href="#" class="footer__el">Для кур’єрів</a>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="footer__reg">Зареєструватися</a>
    <a href="#" class="footer__login-button">Увійти</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container {
  width: 1240px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  min-width: 1240px;
}
.footer {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 125px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.footer__logo {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-right: 187px;
}
.footer__el {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: 57px;
  /*max-width: 467px;*/
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 42px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #838B89;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer__el:hover {
  color: #CECECE;
}
.footer__reg {
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #838B89;
  margin-left: 81px;
  margin-top: 71px;
  padding-right: 28px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.footer__reg:hover {
  color: #585858;
  opacity: 1;
}
.footer__login-button {
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #FF744E;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 42px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.footer__login-button:hover {
  background: #C63E19;
  color: #CECECE;
}
```

upd. перепроверил дивы, все закрыты, тот что без класса добавил просто так, думал бог поможет футер починить, width: 100% тоже не помогло

Comment: Возможно у вас где-то не закрыт Див на странице, в том коде что вы написали, все нормально с дивами, кроме вот этого <div class="">, возможно был написан класс, но стерт

Comment: Еще как вариант попробуйте вот эту строчку в css  max-width: 467px; заменить на width:100%;